# Which resource did you find to be the most helpful when making a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hey, seems to be a few questions on SO about making a ruby gem. I'm interested in those of you that have actually built gems, hoping for Rails3, and your experiences with resources that you have used to make a gem.

My question is the title: Which resource did you find to be the most helpful when making a gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) is an awesome tool that does most of the packaging / gem layout work for you. I've used it in every gem I've made.

Answer (score 1):

I found that intro quite useful to get started:

http://buzaz.com/index.php/2010/01/03/how-to-build-a-ruby-gem/

You could also have a look at this Railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem